# 'std::out_of_range' in virtual function

Tags: c++

I am trying to access the elements of a virtual function which is declared in Class 1 and then defined in Class 2. I understand that the std :: out_of_range error is a memory access problem, but I don't understand the problem in the code main () to access the values.
When calling the function ** m-> function (t, j) ** I cannot access the elements of * parmem *, but if I directly call the output of the function it works: ** parmem.at (1). gamma **. Here is the code:

Class 1:

```
#include <armadillo>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

class Class1
{
public:
mat Y;        

struct Par
{
mat gamma;
} par;
std::vector<Par> parmem ;  
virtual double function( const int t, const int j ) = 0;  
};
```

Class 2:

```
class Class2 : public Class1
{
public:

virtual double function( const int t, const int j );   
};


double Class2::function( const int t, const int j )
{
    cout << parmem.at(t).gamma << endl;
    return j+t;
}
```

main()

```
int main()
{
mat Y=randu<mat>(3,3);

int t=1;
int j=1; 

Class2 *m = new Class2;

std::vector<Class1::Par> parmem {
    {Y},
    {2*Y}
    };

cout << parmem.at(1).gamma << endl; //funciona
cout << m->function(t,j) << endl;  //no funciona
return 0; 
}
```

Thanks for the info.

Comment: Can you convert your question to English please?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your problem is that 'm' is not containing any values in its 'parmem' and therefore the 'at' functions fails.

Comment: Where do you set the value of the `parmem` member of `m`? I don't see that anywhere. Also, please use indentation in your code so that we can read it easily.

Answer (score 1):

In the following lines, you create independent objects:

```
Class2 *m = new Class2;

std::vector<Class1::Par> parmem {
    {Y},
    {2*Y}
    };
```

The `std::vector<Class1::Par> parmem {{Y},{2*Y}};` is not part of the instance of the object `m` is pointing at.

It should work if you assign `parmem` to the object `m` points on by adding `m->parmem = paramen;` to the code.

```
int main()
{
mat Y=randu<mat>(3,3);

int t=1;
int j=1; 

Class2 *m = new Class2;

std::vector<Class1::Par> parmem {
    {Y},
    {2*Y}
    };

m->parmem = paramen;

cout << parmem.at(1).gamma << endl; //funciona
cout << m->function(t,j) << endl;  //no funciona
return 0; 
}
```